# parse JSON without jQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, json

I would like convert the result I get from the ajax call to a JavaScript array. How to do that without using jQuery?

Or it will also be ok is just able to loop the json array without converting to to a JavaScript array.

For now i just need to alert the results to what I get from the ASMX service. Using jQuery is not any option.

Data from request:

```
string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"
[{"Action":"Test1","Target":"#cTarget","Payload":"Hello"},{"Action":"Test2","Target":"#cTarget","Payload":"World"}]
string

      [
           {
                 "Action":"Test1",
                 "Target":"#cTarget",
                 "Payload":"Hello"
           },         
           {
                 "Action":"Test2",
                 "Target":"#cTarget",
                 "Payload":"World"
           }
      ]
```

JavaScript Code

```
  var httpRequest;

    function makeRequest(url, input) {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
            httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
            try {
                httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } 
            catch (e) {
                try {
                    httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } 
                catch (e) {}
            }
        }

        if (!httpRequest) {
            alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
            return false;
        }
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
                if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
                    var results = httpRequest.responseText;
                        var asJavaScriptArray = JSON.parse(results);

                    }
                }
            //}
        };

        httpRequest.open('POST', url);
        httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        httpRequest.send(input);
    }

    var endpointAddress = "Core/RecipeDemo.asmx";
    var url = endpointAddress + "/Base";
    makeRequest(url, "{}");`
```

C# Code

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class RecipeDemo : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string Base()
    {

        List<Recipe> listOfRecipe = new List<Recipe>();
        JavaScriptSerializer  jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        listOfRecipe.Add(new Recipe {Action = "Test1", Payload = "Hello", Target = "#cTarget"});
        listOfRecipe.Add(new Recipe {Action = "Test2", Payload = "World", Target = "#cTarget"});

        return jss.Serialize(listOfRecipe);
                }
}
```

Comment: Then just use the native JSON.parse(TheDataFromRequest) function

Comment: Note that the native JSON functions are only native to IE8+ and real browsers - if you're supporting IE7, you'll need a library like [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should already have something to take a JSON string to object

```
JSON.parse(myJsonString)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

To back from an object to string to `JSON.stringify(myObject)`

Comment: asJavaScriptArray
 Object { d="{"Action":"Test1","Tar...et","Payload":"World"}]"}
 
d="[ 
        {"Action":"Test1","Target":"#cTarget","Payload":"Hello"},
  {"Action":"Test2","Target":"#cTarget","Payload":"World"}
 ]"

Comment: Well i only seem to parse it partly

Answer (score -1):

You do realize that JSON is a valid subset of javascript, don't you?

That means derserializing a JSON string into a Javascript object is as easy as:

```
var json = MakeAjaxRequestHere() ;
var deseralizedJsonObject = eval( '(' + json + ')' ) ;
```

One should note, though, that unless you trust the source of the JSON, eval has some risks as it will evaluate any javascript program. See http://www.json.org/js.html for more.

Comment: Using eval against an ajax response doesn't sound very safe. If the dns or hostfile was poisoned, bad stuff can happen. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don.27t_use_eval.21

Comment: Nooooo! It's a traaaap